# Was Harry related to Salazar Slytherin?

Tags: harry-potter, genealogy

The Potters and the Gaunts are both said to have descended from the Peverell brothers. Voldemort  came from the Gaunt line and was the heir of Salazar Slytherin. Was Harry also the same, or is it that the Peverell brothers were so back in line of ancestry that the divergence of bloodlines digresses the relation?

Comment: He must be related (although *very* distantly), but I don't think we have enough information to say if he was descended or not

Comment: It's not clear I think that the Slytherin line and the Peverell lines are linked (Voldemort may be part of both from different sides somewhere up in his ancestry). It is clear, however, that there's so much inter-marrying between the Wizarding families you'd be hard-pressed to find two wizards who couldn't come up with some convoluted family connection to each other (assuming that neither is muggle born or child of two muggle borns...)

Comment: @TZHX That is a point Sirius raised in OOTP too, which is why i am confused about the ancestry of Harry

Comment: @Slytherincess I'm not convinced these are dupes. Your answer to that question establishes 1) Harry and Voldemort have common ancestry in the Peverells and 2) Harry is not descended from Gryffindor. That doesn't preclude the possibility that Slytherin is an ancestor of both Peverell brothers. Or have I missed something?

Comment: @Slytherincess your answer explains the no relation part of harry and gryffindor. but what i have asked is the ancestory relation between harry and slytherin. am i missing siomething here ?

Answer (score 22):

**He's related somewhere, but Slytherin isn't his ancestor.**

There was a debunked rumour on [J.K. Rowling's old website](https://web.archive.org/web/20070606211212/http:/www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/rumours_view.cfm?id=3) which mentions this topic obliquely:

> **Voldemort is Harry's real father/grandfather/close relative of some description**
>
> No, no, no, no, no. You lot have been watching much too much Star Wars. James is DEFINITELY Harry's father. Doesn't everybody Harry meets say “you look just like your father”? And hasn't Dumbledore already told Harry that Voldemort is the last surviving descendent of Salazar Slytherin? Just to clarify – **this means that Harry is NOT a descendent of Salazar Slytherin**.

It is almost certain that Slytherin and Harry are related *somehow* (the connection with the Peverell brothers ensures this is the case), but the connection is likely to be incredibly distant and probably too far back in their family trees to be meaningful.

Comment: JKR has said that Harry and Voldemort are "distantly related" through the Peverell family, but, as you say, that doesn't make Harry Voldemort's descendant. :)

Comment: Given how wizards value "pure blood" and how there aren't that many wizard families, I'm guessing all pure-blood wizards are **very closely** related.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the Peverell brothers predate Slytherin?  Their exploits have passed into legends most wizards don't believe.  Slytherin seems more hard history.  Slytherin, the Gaunts, and Voldemort could be descended from one of the other two brothers, while Harry is descended from the one who got the cloak.